# How do you even use ant design's ConfigProvider in React?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I see in the antd docs, there is option to use ConfigProvider, where I can customize some styles or some behaviors.
In my case I want to customize outline style of elements(when I focus on input, it gives blue outline ring, so I just wanna make it green).

I wrapped my whole App inside ConfigProvider. But I can't find any example of code of actual customizing.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: this is not as simple as it sounds.  depends on how your setup is configured.  are you using Create React App? are you using UMI? did you eject?...... we need more information and we need to see your setup. we need to see enough to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Okay) I will add some additional information later today

Comment: try to use these two docs pages: 
https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme - there're examples
https://ant.design/components/input#design-token - there're design tokens to modify, you probably need `controlOutline`

Answer (score 0):

One usage of ConfigProvider is the `locale` prop, which customizes things like `DatePicker` to the correct internationalized settings (month, days of week) based on the locale passed in.

https://4x.ant.design/docs/react/i18n